# Problem seeing how Baire's theorem applies in a proof of open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, baire-category

[image]

I cant see which version and how they use Baires theorem to get that atleast on $MB_{n}$ is dense in some open set. Any version of Baires theorem needs open or closed sets. I can get neither on the $MB_{n}$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Def'n. A set  $S$ is nowhere-dense iff $Int \bar S=\emptyset.$... Lemma: If $S$ is nowhere dense then  $\bar S$ is nowhere dense... Theorem .(Baire): If $ A$ is a completely metrizable space and $F$ is a non-empty countable family of dense open subsets of $A$ then $\cap F$ is dense in$ A.$... Corollary : If $A$ is a non-empty completely metrizable space and $G$ is a countable family of nowhere-dense subsets of $A$ then $\cup G\ne A.$... Proof of Corollary :The case $G=\emptyset$ is  trivial. If $G\ne \emptyset$ let $ F= \{A\backslash \bar g : g\in G\}.$ Then $\cap F$ is dense in $A,$ so $\emptyset\ne \cap F \subset (A\backslash \cup G).$....Therefore, if $ Int_U (Cl_U M B_n)=\emptyset$ for every $ n,$ we could not have $\cup_nM B_n=U.$

Comment: This I got aswell, but why then we got $A \subset IntMB_{n}  \subset Cl MB_{n}$. For some open $A$, howcome some $MB_{n}$ is dense in this $A$?

Comment: "S is dense in T" means by def'n that $\bar S\supset T$.